# Terraform - What would be the variable type for any values

Tags: terraform

What would be the correct method to specify a type for a variable which is a `List with map and the map with any type of values.

I tried `type = list(map(any))` any but I get the error `element 0: all map elements must have the same type.`

```
variable "ingress_rules" {
  type = list(map(any))
}
```

I wonder if I should not specify anything for the type at all?

Here is the ingress_rules looks like:

```
module "prod_security_groups" {
  source = "../modules/security_groups"

  name = "Inbout traffic for WebServers"
  ingress_rules = [
    {description: "Port 3306", cidr_blocks: ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24"], port: 3306, protocol: "tcp"},
    {description: "Port 22",   cidr_blocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"], port: 22, protocol: "tcp"},
    {description: "port 80",   cidr_blocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"], port: 80, protocol: "tcp"}
  ]
  tags = {
    Name = "SG WebServers"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type is really an optional thing.

Map really supports only a certain type, all elements of it should be either strings or ints or something else. What you have is a list of objects so you can try to use:

```
  type = list(
    object({
      description = string
      cidr_blocks = list(string)
      port        = number
      protocol    = string
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "ingress_rules" {
  type = any
}
```

Comment: Please add why this is advisable, esp. how it is better than `not specify anything for the type at all`.